# iphone nsurlconnection async, wait for done

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, asynchronous, wait

My code has a function (F1) to return YES/NO based on information read from server. So it uses async nsurlconnection to receive data.
So F1 starts connection and MUST wait for data to be loaded

The question is how can i implement it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Don't.** Find a way to use asynchronous calls. You must not pause the run loop while waiting for results; your application will be killed.

Instead, re-factor your code to return control to Cocoa and make the completion resume your processing.

I think WWDC Session #200 covers this.